# PHP Division by zero error where no math is present?

Tags: php, session

```
Warning: Division by zero in ..\session.php on line 2
```

After updating my PHP to the most current version my host allows (5.5.9) there was a small issue with the session path so I had to include a small snip-it of code before the session_start() to fix it. However this odd error is happening, apparently it thinks I am attempting to divide by zero? I would like to know how to fix that if it is possible, I assume it is just PHP being stupid however.

Thanks! :)

Below is the first few lines of code

```
<?php
session_save_path(“/tmp”);
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
```

EDIT: Fixed the issue using the code below

```
session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
```

Comment: Your problem should not derive from these lines. Could you show more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the difference in the quotes used. PHP thinks you're trying to divide a string by another string. Change that to regular double-quotes and the problem will be resolved.

Right now, this is what PHP sees:

```
“/tmp”
^--- first string
 ^--- division operator
  ^^^^--- second string
```

The [string is cast to an `int`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) before the operation, and that effectively turns both sides to `0`, hence causing the `Division by zero` warning. You'd have caught this if you had [enabled error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393).

Comment: Increasing the error reporting level would have helped to identify this: http://codepad.org/XaJcv1xo

Comment: very well explained one up from me :)

Comment: How would I do this without the use of 'smart' quotes as I attempted already to swap for normal quotes and that only ruins the fix. (Noob PHP coder)

Comment: @Darkaaja: By smart, I assume he meant irregular quotes. **`”` is different from `"`**. The command should use proper quotes: `session_save_path("/tmp");` - please explain how normal quotes "ruin your fix".

Comment: @Darkaaja Smart quotes mean nothing to PHP, as this code shows, so if they appeared to be fixing a problem, something else was happening. Since division by zero still returns something (boolean false), what you are actually doing is `session_save_path(false);` which will in turn be the same as `session_save_path('');` but I'm not quite sure what that will actually do.

Answer (score 1):

You have smart quotes.

Your code is therefore being interpreted as:

- Unquoted string literal `“`
- Divide by...
- Unquoted string literal `tmp“`

Division casts to numbers, both sides get cast to zero, result is `0/0`.

Comment: How would I do this without the use of 'smart' quotes as I attempted already to swap for normal quotes and that only ruins the fix. (Noob PHP coder)

Comment: This is indeed what is happening, and becomes clearer with Notices enabled, as shown in this demo: http://3v4l.org/iaquX